# What is the name of this plant which is located in Hyderabad city of Telangana State,India?

Tags: species-identification

I found this plant in Hyderabad city of Telangana State,India.Many people of Hyderabad city have planted this flowering plant.I don't know the name of this plant.If it's flower treated as a circle,the flower has diameter of nearly 6cm length.Can any one tell me what is the name of this plant?[image]

Answer (score 6):

From the twisted overlapping appearance of the petals it is a member of the Apocynaceae family.  So I searched for "Apocyanaceae india" and found images consistent with your picture.  Good chance it is *Allamanda blanchetii* or Purple Allamanda.  Here is a picture comparable to yours ([source/CC0](https://www.pixcove.com/purple-allamanda-apocynaceae-allamanda-blanchetii-allamanda-violacea-flower-kodagu-floret-india/)).

[image]

Here's a bit about the [plant](http://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Purple%20Allamanda.html) and Wikipedia has a [short page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allamanda_blanchetii).