# Allamanda blanchetti fertilization mechanism

Tags: botany, sexual-reproduction, flowers, asexual-reproduction

Here is an *[Allamanda blanchetti](https://toptropicals.com/catalog/uid/allamanda_cherry.htm)* flower in my garden.

My question is based on the observation that the flower seems to be devoid of any reproductive structures, *i.e.,* Stamen or Carpel, so how does it set seed? In the picture below it can be seen that the plant isn't sterile and successfully produces seed pods.

[image: Large maroon flower][image: Spiny flattened pod like fruit]

Comment: google lens app can recognize flowers 95% of the time.

Comment: Since the species identification portion of your question is a duplicate, I encourage you to  remove that portion. That will allow you to focus on a single question, which is important because each question should be posted separately. That improves the chances that you will get answers for each question and makes the answers more accessible for future users. ——— However, we expect you to do research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Start by looking up reproduction of this species. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific about the fertilization process, since @Bryan Hanson has already pointed out a similar question for the species ID. But the question  as it stands now, edited, is different and not a duplicate.

Comment: Great, I've voted to reopen your question. This typically requires four other users to agree so it may take a few days. In the meantime I encourage you to dissect some of the flowers and see whether you can find out an answer yourself! A razor blade or sharp knife can be used to cut through the flowers to see what is inside — I suggest cutting along the long axis of the flower (slicing the "tube" at the base lengthwise). I think you will find this quite enlightening. However, it may lead to more questions, but that's good! (Also be careful to clean up the latex since it may be irritating.)

Comment: @tyersome sure! I will try it out as soon as possible. :)

Comment: There's now a followup question with dissection photos at [What are these structures inside a cut open Allamanda blanchetti?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/96096/what-are-these-structures-inside-a-cut-open-allamanda-blanchetti)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the ID goes, this looks like *Allamanda blanchetti*.  See this [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/88587/32892).

Comment: In the future I think it would be better if you just flagged the question as a duplicate of the other question (to which you gave a good answer).

Comment: I have looked up the reproduction of Allamanda genus on Wikipedia and other websites, but only taxonomy, distribution ,medicinal uses and the likes are listed. I am a high school student and don't really have much access to more scholarly articles. So please enlighten me on the matter.